# GET operations cannot have a body error while Android calling WCF web service

Tags: android, wcf, web-services, get

My android application is calling WCF web services yet I can't send my get request :

This my WCF contract

```
[OperationContract]
    [WebGet(UriTemplate = "ValidateLogin/{userId}/{password}",
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
        BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped)]
    LoginValidation ValidateLogin(string userId, string password);
```

and I'm calling this on my Android app

```
public String ValidateLogin(ArrayList<NameValuePair> httgetArgs){

    String result = "";

    String url = "http://10.0.2.2/WSCom.svc/ValidateLogin";
    InputStream is = null;
    try {
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        setparameters(url , new UrlEncodedFormEntity(httgetArgs));

        HttpGet httget = new HttpGet(url);

        httget.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
        httget.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");


        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httget);

        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

        is = entity.getContent();

    } 
        catch (Exception e) {
        result = e.toString();
    }

    try {
        result = readStream(is); 

        is.close();
    } 
    catch (Exception e) {

        result = e.toString();
    }
    return (result);
    }
```

But I got the error as

> Operation 'ValidateLogin' in contract 'IWSCom' uses GET, but also has body parameter 'userId'. GET operations cannot have a body. Either make the parameter 'userId' a UriTemplate parameter, or switch from WebGetAttribute to WebInvokeAttribute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String user = "";
String pass = "";
String url = "http://10.0.2.2/WSCom.svc/ValidateLogin/" + user + "/" + pass;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to have url as below

```
String url = "http://10.0.2.2/WSCom.svc/ValidateLogin/YourUserId/Password";
```

As you are passing the data in url you need not use

```
setparameters(url , new UrlEncodedFormEntity(httgetArgs));
```